# Javascript string.replace with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I want to replace a url querystring parameter with a new value if it already exists or add it on if not.

e.g.

The current url could be:
a. `www.mysite.com/whatever.asp?page=5&version=1` **OR**
b. `www.mysite.com/whatever.asp?version=1`

I need the resulting url to be `www.mysite.com/whatever.asp?page=1&version=1`

I suspect I can use string.replace with a regex to do this the most intelligent way but am hoping for a little help with it from someone more experienced with regexs :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the clearest solution would be to write one regex that parses the URL, and then build a URL from there.  Here's what I would do:

```
function urlCleanup(url) {
  var match = /http:\/\/www\.mysite\.com\/whatever.asp\?(page=(\d+))?&?(version=(\d+))?/.exec(url);
  var page = match[2] ? match[2] : "0";
  var version = match[4] ? match[4] : "0";
  return "http://www.mysite.com/whatever.asp?page=" + page + "&version=" + version;
}

var testUrls = [ "http://www.mysite.com/whatever.asp?page=4"
               , "http://www.mysite.com/whatever.asp?version=5"
               , "http://www.mysite.com/whatever.asp?page=4&version=5" ];

for(i in testUrls)
  console.log(urlCleanup(testUrls[i]));
```

One problem this doesn't handle is having the variables in the opposite order in the url (e.g. `?version=5&page=2`).  To handle that, it would probably make more sense to use two regexes to search the URL for each parameter, like this:

```
function urlCleanup(url) {
  var match, page, version;
  match = /version=(\d+)/.exec(url);
  version = match ? match[1] : "0";
  match = /page=(\d+)/.exec(url);
  page = match ? match[1] : "0";

  return "http://www.mysite.com/whatever.asp?page=" + page + "&version=" + version;
}

var testUrls = [ "http://www.mysite.com/whatever.asp?page=4"
               , "http://www.mysite.com/whatever.asp?version=5"
               , "http://www.mysite.com/whatever.asp?version=5&page=2"
               , "http://www.mysite.com/whatever.asp?page=4&version=5" ];

for(i in testUrls)
  console.log(urlCleanup(testUrls[i]));
```

Comment: Max respect :P Let me play with it for a bit now :)

Comment: I'm playing with what I wrote here in a console, and it's not quite right, I'll edit in a much cleaner version shortly.

Comment: Its actually only the `page` part that I need to play with. If `page` parameter exists, replace it with new one, otherwise add it to the end

Comment: Oh, crap.  My answer is far too complex for what you need then, sorry I misread the question.  For that, you just need a subset of my second code block -- let me know if it's not obvious what you need to do.

Comment: This helped me solve the problem by using your regex examples, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather use `location.search` along with some `.splits()` and [`Array.prototype.some`<sup>help</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```
var s     = location.search.slice(1).split(/&/);
    check = s.some(function(elem) {
        return elem.split(/=/)[0] === 'page';
    });

if(!check) s.push('page=1');

location.href = location.hostname + location.pathname + '?' + s.join('&');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I gave it to Benson as I used his to solve my problem and for the lesson in regexs :P